# Is it possible to write build message from powershellscript?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, tfsbuild

If i have a build template for TFS, and in this template in post-build script row i make a call to a powershell script, are there any way to transfer output from this PS script to build log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "invokeprocess" workflow activity to invoke powershell and  write stdOutput and errOutput to buildlog.